# Election history says no elections currently underway when there are

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, election, serverfault

I was just looking at Server Fault to see how the election process worked on a bigger site.  I decided to look at [last years history](https://serverfault.com/election/2012) and was surprised to see

> **There are no active community moderator elections at the moment**. Below is a historical record of all elections to date:

Almost immediately below the site-wide banner prodding people towards the ongoing election.  Don't know if it's a bug or by design but thought I'd flag it up.

Comment: ...where did you get that URL? `/election/2012` is not a valid way to get to the election, that'd be `/election/2` (2nd election since the system was in place).  Yes that page's text is incorrect, but the correct behavior would be a 404 of sorts.

Comment: It's not linked (that I know of), I simply followed the syntax from English.SE ([english/election/2011](http://english.stackexchange.com/election/2011)), which incidentally is the same page displayed when there is no election (as in the case of [english/election](http://english.stackexchange.com/election/) at present).

Comment: @Rory Er. Where'd you find the English.SE syntax then? The number after /election is the election ID -- you're asking to see the 2012th SF election. There isn't one, so it just shows the election list. Normally you'd only see the election list if there's no pending elections (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/election/)), so the text is apparently written assuming that's true. So in short, this is a bug, but also the `/election` links you're using are wrong